# What's wrong with my heap sort implementation in python?

Tags: python, heapsort

```
nums = [-2, 3, 9, 5, 4, 22, -12, 7, 14, -4, 1]

# places an element in the correct index of the list of the corresponding binary tree
def heapify(arr, i):
    arrlen = len(arr)
    leftChildIndex = 2*i + 0
    rightChildIndex = 2*i + 1 

    # compare the argument element with its children
    if leftChildIndex < arrlen and arr[leftChildIndex] > arr[i]:
        max = leftChildIndex
    else:
        max = i

    if rightChildIndex < arrlen and arr[rightChildIndex] > arr[max]:
        max = rightChildIndex
   

    # swap if necessary
    if max != i:
        temp = arr[i]
        arr[i] = arr[max]
        arr[max] = temp
        heapify(arr, max)

# build max heap using heapify()
def buildMaxHeap(arr):
    arrlen = len(arr)

    for i in reversed(range(arrlen//2)):
        heapify(arr, i)

# the main sort function
def heapSort(arr):
    buildMaxHeap(arr)
    n = len(arr)
    while n >= 0:
        for i in reversed(range(n)):
            temp = arr[i]
            arr[i] = arr[0]
            arr[0] = temp
            heapify(arr, 0)
        n -= 1
        

def main():
    heapSort(nums)
    print(nums)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I think it's probably in the main heap sort function but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The output I'm getting is `[-4, 3, 5, -12, 1, 4, 7, 9, 14, 22, -2]`. Am I calling the `heapify()` function correctly? I tested the `buildMaxHeap()` function and it seems to be working properly.

Comment: `heapify(arr[], 0)` What is `arr[]`?  That's not valid python.

Comment: Well, did you try to diagnose the problem? Do you understand what the results should be at each step of the process? For example, if you looked at the result from `buildMaxHeap`, would you be able to tell if it's correct? Did you try doing that? *Is* it correct? How about each time through the loop in `heapSort` - what should happen each time through the loop? What *does* happen?

Comment: Are there any errors or tracebacks? If so, please [edit] your question and post their [**full text**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text.

Comment: Also, `arr[]` isn't valid syntax, so if you're getting output at all, this isn't your actual code. But assuming that you actually have `arr` in your code, here's a hint: where you declared `heapify(arr, i):`, what is the intended purpose of `i`? Therefore, as you start pulling out values from your heap, and re-heapifying the rest, what value of `i` should you use? What value *do* you use?

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to fix the problem yourself first; this isn't a debugging service.

Comment: yea sorry the arr[] was a typo, the result of the buildMaxHeap() function seems to be correct as I said. In the main heapsort function, I assume heapify should be called on elements of arr[:i], since it's recursive should it be heapify(arr, i) then? I tried that but it still gives a wrong result.